# Phonegap & Jquery - Custom progress bar

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

since PhoneGap doesn't support sql migration yet and android doesn't support html5 progress tag yet, I decided to create my own, problem is I don't know how to do it.

I wanted to populate sql table with progress bar, informing the user how many done and how much left to do.

Here's what it should look like:

```
function injectSql() {

    // lineToUse =  sql query()  
    // lineToUse =  sql query()
    // and so on.  I don't want to use var as there are plenty of this injections and it'll crash the phone.
    return LineToUse;
}

function sqlCounter() {

   var injThisLine = injectSql(lineToUse);

   db.transaction (
     function(t){
       db.executeSql(injThisLine);
     });

   alert (injThisLineKey + 'out of nn');
}
```

Apologies if am not making any sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Progress Bar code that we can use.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

You can import the JS and CSS file given on the link above and then you can use the below code on Android WebApp.

```
    $(function() {

        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
        setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);

        });

        function updateProgress() {
          var progress;
          progress = $("#progressbar")
            .progressbar("option","value");
          if (progress < 100) {
              $("#progressbar")
                .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 5);
              setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);
          }
        }
```

This will move the progress with the increment of five after delay of half second. You can modify it as per the need.

Please let me know if this helps you

Kind Regards,

Summved